# How to Connect 3 Networks With Ethernet and WIFi/VPN?

Tags: networking, routing, vpn, ethernet

I have two computers on a robot that are directly connected via Ethernet. Called" Magni" and "Jetson". Magni is connected to a wireless network. On this wireless network, there is a third computer "PC" that is connected to the Magni via Wireguard VPN.
I have two computers on a robot that are directly connected via Ethernet. Called" Magni" and "Jetson". Magni is connected to a wireless network. On this wireless network, there is a third computer "PC" that is connected to the Magni via Wireguard VPN.

[image: Picture of Network Setup]

The goal is to be able to send and receive messages from all components of the system to one another. The Magni - Jetson and Magni - PC pairs can ping, discover, and publish to each other. The issue I am having is communication between my PC and the Jetson. I attempted to do some IP forwarding. Where first on the jetson I added a route from the static 192.168.131.1 IP to the Magni's VPN 10.0.0.161. After doing so I am able to ping the Magni's VPN address 10.0.0.161 from the jetson.

```
sudo route add -net 10.0.0.0  netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.131.1
```

Then on my PC, I attempted to add a similar route...

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.131.0  netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.161
```

From my PC I then tried to communicate with the jetson (via ping). However, I am not able to successfully communicate with the Jetson. From the PC when trying to ping the Jetson, I get this error with my current set up.

```
PING 192.168.131.2 (10.0.0.66) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.66 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Required key not available
```

I have also tried other routes to no avail. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction as to how to resolve this issue as I am not too experienced in networking.

PC's Kernel IP routing table

```
Destination   Gateway     Genmask       Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0           10.147.x.x      0.0.0.0         UG   600    0        0  wlp2s0

10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0

10.147.x.x      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     600    0        0 wlp2s0

169.xxx.x.x     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0

192.168.131.0   10.0.0.161      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 wg0
```

Magni's Kernel IP routing table

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         10.147.x.x      0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0

10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0

10.19.xxx.xxx   10.147.x.x      255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlan0

10.147.x.x      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     600    0        0 wlan0

192.168.131.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enxb827eb452fa3
```

Jetson's Kernel IP routing table

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

10.0.0.0           192.168.131.1   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0

169.xxx.x.x       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0

192.168.131.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

Comment: What about firewalls, IP forwarding, etc? How do you establish wireguard connection? Does wireguard make some additional routes? I had a very similar problem, and here is the solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602267/wireguard-connection-between-to-lans-with-wireguard-boxes-behind-routers/620628#620628. I hope you can find something useful there.

Answer (score 1):

`ping: sendmsg: Required key not available` means it's a WireGuard [cryptokey routing](https://www.wireguard.com/#cryptokey-routing) issue. In WireGuard, the key has an association to the route and vice versa. This is an internal WireGuard routing made in addition to the standard routing:

> At the heart of WireGuard is a concept called Cryptokey Routing, which
> works by associating public keys with a list of tunnel IP addresses
> that are allowed inside the tunnel.

That means you didn't add the required `AllowedIPs` (`wg-quick`) / `allowed-ips` (direct `wg` command) parameters.

When a WG interface is about to send a packet it matches the destination IP to a public key's `AllowedIPs` in order to encrypt it with this key. When a WG interface received a packet, it validates the source IP with the peer's public key's `AllowedIPs`: this value is used both ways.

To fix this, on the PC add in the configuration, under the relevant Magni Peer public key entry in the wg-quick configuration and restart the tunnel:

```
AllowedIPs = 192.168.131.0/24
```

Actually for this specific case `AllowedIPs = 192.168.131.1,192.168.131.2` would be sufficient.

If you could already ping the Magni (192.168.131.1) from the PC, that should be enough, assuming Magni was set as router.

---

Else, there's the equivalent to do on the other WireGuard peer, Magni. Do the equivalent to match the PC, under the PC's Peer public key entry:

```
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/24
```

Again `AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.66` would be sufficient to reach only the PC here.

It could be done directly with a `wg` command instead for immediate (and not saved) effect (as an example a randomly generated Peer's public key value `ukFU7nbX5NoEJTLb5rizqcfB093fv8VfuLFA57q3oG4=` is used here, please change it to the PC's public key):

```
wg set wg0 peer ukFU7nbX5NoEJTLb5rizqcfB093fv8VfuLFA57q3oG4= allowed-ips 10.0.0.0/24
```